# How can I use the Banach fixed-point Theorem to find approximately the Omega Constant?

Tags: mathematical-physics, fixed-point-theorems

I know how to find the Omega constant using Newton's method, however, I was trying to compute the Omega constante $$\Omega \approx 0, 567143290409783872999968662210 ...$$ by using Banach Fixed-Point Theorem in the equation $x=e^{-x}$. As far as I know, we should define some $T(x) = e^{-x}$ then prove that $T(x)$ is a contraction. Then, we Shold iterate that contraction in order to find the constant. However, I cannot prove that $T(x)$ is a contraction and doing the iteration I do not find the Omega constant.

Comment: The Banach fixed point theorem simply says there exists a fixed point, but doesn't provide a method to find it. I'm not sure what you are referring to.

Comment: Do you mean something like $e^{-e^{-e^{\dots}}}$?

Comment: In fact $T$ is not a contraction (at least not on $\mathbb{R}$). However iterates converge to the unique fixed point of $T$. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4302383/convergence-of-fixed-point-iteration-for-omega-constant/4302516#4302516

Comment: Don Thousand, as far as I know the Theorem also provides a method to find it, at least in the prove of the Theorem. And Bonnaduck, yes it was what I mean, but by doing it, I can't find the constant valeu and I don't know why.